# hmsegmentedcontrol - When I scroll, the tab highlighter always changes to 0. why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uisegmentedcontrol, contentoffset

In [HMSegmentControl](https://github.com/HeshamMegid/HMSegmentedControl), I have added tableview in one of the segment View. When I am on the current section and I scroll up or down, I noticed that the tab highlighter always changes to 0. Why is it happening?

This is my scrollView code:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGFloat pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width;
    int page = scrollView.contentOffset.x / pageWidth;
    [self.chatSegment setSelectedSegmentIndex:page animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"scrollViewDidScroll - You are now on page %i",page);
}
```

Log Value:

```
<UITableView: 0x128007e00; frame = (0 0; 320 568); clipsToBounds = YES; tag = 502; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x1276c2690>; layer = <CALayer: 0x1276c20e0>; contentOffset: {0, 2}; contentSize: {320, 570}>
```

Comment: we don't know what HMSegmentedControl is! Did you log the page value ? Is it 0 while you scroll ?

Comment: I'm getting scrollView.contentOffset.x as 0.

Comment: and that makes the segment to select the 0 index.  Are you asking why do you get 0 for scrollView content offset ?

Comment: yes. why its getting as 0

Comment: you should add more details. what is the scrollview content size ?

Comment: ok. I have add object value. scrollview content size is contentSize: {320, 570}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a table is scrolled in vertical direction, the offset y value will be changed , x value will always be 0.

So in you case, you should refer to `scrollView.contentOffset.y`